# How do I prove by mathematical induction that $n!<n^{n-1}$ where $n\geq3$? Did I do it right?

Tags: induction

Suppose $n$ is equal or bigger than $3$. It's obviously true for $n=3$ that $n!<n^{n-1}$. To show more generally that

$$k! < k^{k-1} \text{ for some } k,$$

is it as simple as saying

$$(k+1)! = (k+1)k! \implies (k+1)!\lt k^k\:\:?$$

I'm new to induction so I am not sure I got it right. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - do you want to show that $n!<n^n-1$ or $n!<n^{n-1}$? You have it both ways in the question.

Comment: I believe it's cleared up now, it's n^(n-1) (I don't know how to format, I apologize for that)

Comment: Yes - I see it's corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need induction? $n! = 2\cdot3\cdots n<n\cdot n \cdots n = n^{n-1}$

Comment: Well it's obviously true, the exercise requires me to do it by induction, though...

Comment: @JohnDoe I hope my answer will help you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing that it's true for $3$
$$3^2\gt3!$$
Assume that it's true for $k$
$$k^{k-1}\gt k!\tag{1}$$
we can see clearly that
$$(k+1)^{k-1}\gt k^{k-1}$$
$$\implies (k+1)^{k-1}\gt k!$$
Multiplying Both side by $(k+1)$
$$(k+1)(k+1)^{k-1}\gt (k+1)k!$$

$$(k+1)^{k}\gt (k+1)!$$
if it's true for $k$ then it's true for $k+1$ and then by Induction Hypothesis....

Comment: That's it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Done. I asked the question in a bit of a rush... didn't get to figure out the specifics of how the site works.